# Redis regular timeouts on Docker

Tags: redis, docker, stackexchange.redis

We are using the latest Redis Docker and finding that we get periodic timeouts (12 in the last 4 hours).

The errors are things like:

```
Timeout performing PING, inst: 51, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 3, qu=0, qs=3, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=0/1
Timeout performing PING, inst: 51, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 4, qu=0, qs=4, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=28/0
Timeout performing GET Prod.Cust.Agent.118, inst: 100, mgr: ProcessReadQueue, queue: 3, qu=0, qs=3, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=630/1
```

Looking at the help for Latency timeouts with Redis (http://redis.io/topics/latency) I'm wondering what if any settings need to be changed on:

```
a. the docker
b. the server running the docker
```

For instance:
The help suggests:

```
Transparent huge pages must be disabled from your kernel. Use echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled to disable them, and restart your Redis process.
```

Is that something that should be done on docker or the Server?

When I check the value on the server I get:

```
jhilden@Omega:~$  more /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[always] madvise never
```

Thanks in advance for the advice.